# Ruby Sinatra Embed erb Partial External HTML File

Tags: ruby, sinatra, embed, erb

I have a need to hold a "Purchase Contract" type of report in my website.  I am using `Sinatra` using `erb` files to deliver content.  I would like to email the current report (the versions will change) out when people sign up for various items.

I'm thinking I can house it in the database, or an external file, in some kind of format, so I can do the both:

- import it into an `erb` file for presentation on the web
- use it in an email so it's readable in text format

So basically I need it in a format that's basic as possible, but it has to translate into `HTML` (`erb`) and text.

What are my options with the format of this file?  And how can I translate that into HTML?  I've looked at `markdown` and it's not very pretty with the `gems` that I find that translate to text.  Seeing that it needs plain text as well as `HTML` I'm a bit lost as to how to get this done.

**File Snippet**

```
Privacy Policy
Updated Feb 20, 2019

Website.com (“Website”) is a private business. In this Privacy Statement the terms “we” and “our” refer to Website. This Privacy Statement explains Website’s practices regarding personal information of our users and visitors to this website (the “Website”), as well as those who have transactions with us through telephone, Internet, faxes and other means of communications.

Website’s Commitment to Privacy
At Website, we are committed to respecting the privacy of our members and our Website visitors. For that reason we have taken, and will continue to take, measures to help protect the privacy of personal information held by us.

This Privacy Statement provides you with details regarding: (1) how and why we collect personal information; (2) what we do with that information; (3) the steps that we take to help ensure that access to that information is secure; (4) how you can access personal information pertaining to you; and (5) who you should contact if you have questions and concerns about our policies or practices.
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking but it's certainly possible. Take a look at [sinatra partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial).

Comment: @iain Yes I will restructure the question.

Comment: Have you seen the [docs for ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)? Using that you should be able to render the template from anywhere. Also have a read of the Views/Templates section of the [Sinatra README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html). If it's still not clear to you after that then give me a shout and I'll write something longer below.

Comment: @iain Yes I have.  Been using `erb` for quite some time. I got a `File.read(filepath)` to output, but it's not formatted properly (privacy.txt).  I've been over the Sinatra README quite often and it's still confusing for the most part.

Comment: I've put the answer below, if you've any questions add some comments to it and I'll try to expand on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: Save the file as `HTML` and use this gem for conversion into `text`:

https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text_ruby

Works fine if the `HTML` is simple enough.

**Remaining**: Still have the issue as using the `HTML` file as a `partial`.

**Solved**:

```
@text = markdown File.read('views/privacy.md')
```

So park the source file as a `markdown` file, which can translate to `HTML`.  When I need the `email` version, I need to translate to `HTML` then to `text` using the `HTML2text` gem.  https://rubygems.org/gems/html2text

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have a portion of text (stored in a database or a file, it doesn't really matter where) and you want to:

- serve this up formatted as HTML via a webpage
- send it plain via email

Assuming a standard Sinatra project layout where the views directory lives in the project dir, e.g.

```
project-root/
  app.rb
  views/
```

and a route to deliver the text in `app.rb`:

```
get "/sometext" do

end
```

If you put the `erb` template in the `views` directory and as the last line of the route make a call to the `erb` template renderer you should get the output in HTML. e.g.

```
project-root/
  app.rb
  views/
    sometext.erb # this is the erb template
```

In the Sinatra app

```
# app.rb
# I'm assuming you've some way to differentiate
# bits of text, e.g.
get "/sometext/:id" do |id|
  @text = DB.sometext.getid id # my fake database call
  erb :sometext # <- this will render it, make it the final statement of the block
  # make sure @text is in the template
  # else use locals, e.g.
  # erb :sometext, :locals => { text: @text }
end
```

Now when a user visits `http://example.org/sometext/485995` they will receive HTML. Emailing the text to the user could be triggered via the website or some other method of your choice.

Comment: I've been serving `HTML` for some time using this method.  But it's `HTML`.  The text file is plain `text`.  Serving it isn't the issue.  It's translating the `text` file to `HTML` while retaining the text in the original file so it's easy to email.

Comment: @Rich_F I'm must be missing something obvious. You already have the text stored somewhere because you pass it to the template, right?

Comment: Yes.  But the formatting doesn't change to `HTML` while respecting `<CR>`, etc.

Comment: @Rich_F Are you able to add to your question an example of the text (even a few lines) and examples of how you want the HTML and email to format it? I think that would make things clear.

Comment: Will provide a snippet.  The `email` doesn't need to format anything.  Getting text to `HTML` is an issue though.  I don't care how I store the original.  I want the same going to both `email` and `HTML`.

Comment: @Rich_F Thanks. Does ERB collapse those linebreaks? I'd try wrapping the text in a `<pre>` HTML tag.

Comment: Yes. It becomes one big paragraph.  Using `<pre>` tags would screw up the email version.  But I will try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188974/discussion-between-iain-and-rich-f).

Comment: Will get to it tomorrow.  It is 2am here.